# How to find the mismatch values from a date column in pandas

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, datetime

The data frame contains 10 million records .
All the columns are in 'str' data type .

let consider this as my data frame .

```
      id location name       Dob      death   
0  11066  location 481 2017-02-01 2017-02-03    
1  18000  location 962 1990-01-27 2016-01-26     
2  16964  location 491 1sssssssss 2016-01-26   
3   4795  location 532 1990-01-29 2016-01-26   
4   3392  location 600 1990-01/30 2016-01-26
```

I want to find out the rows/observations where the value of 'Dob' column is not a date type .

Expected out put :

```
   id     location name       Dob          death    
2  16964  location 491       1sssssssss    2016-01-26     
4   3392  location 600       1990-01/30    2016-01-26
```

I already try the below code but its quite slow in terms of execution speed .

Sample Code :

```
temp_list = list()
for index, data in enumerate(df['Dob']):
     try:
        pd.to_datetime(data)
     except:
        temp_list.append(index)
```

Any alternative way which is more faster in execution .

Answer (score 1):

You need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameters `errors='coerce'` for return `NaT` if values not match format `%Y-%m-%d`, then check `NaT` by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.Dob, errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d'))
0   2017-02-01
1   1990-01-27
2          NaT
3   1990-01-29
4          NaT
Name: Dob, dtype: datetime64[ns]

mask = pd.to_datetime(df.Dob, errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d').isnull()
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Dob, dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
      id  location  name         Dob       death
2  16964  location   491  1sssssssss  2016-01-26
4   3392  location   600  1990-01/30  2016-01-26
```

---

If omit `format`, `to_datetime` try converting, so maybe some values will be cast to `DateTime` and NO in output:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.Dob, errors='coerce'))
0   2017-02-01
1   1990-01-27
2          NaT
3   1990-01-29
4   1990-01-30
Name: Dob, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df[pd.to_datetime(df.Dob, errors='coerce').isnull()])
      id  location  name         Dob       death
2  16964  location   491  1sssssssss  2016-01-26
```